# Can I upload a website made with Node.js to a web host?

Tags: node.js

I am making a website with node.js and I was wondering if I just upload it with Filezilla like any other website. Sorry for this stupid question

Comment: You're going to have to run the `node` software and point it to your application, uploading probably won't get you far unless you have a provider that handles this kind of stuff automatically ( Which is probably not the case )

Comment: Your host needs to run Node.js.  Most hosts do not support that.  Ask them.

Comment: You'll have to run it with `node`. It won't just magically run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for VPS(Virtual Private Server) or PaaS(Platform as a Service) as per your requirement, price and skill set.

Ideally you should choose VPS If you are capable to manage your server by yourself like node installation, Server configuration, database handling, High Availability, Load Balancing, http routing and Service backup policies etc. Some VPS providers: [Linode](https://www.linode.com/), [DigitalOcean](http://www.dreamhost.com/), [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

PaaS is always preferable if you don't want to manage your production and more over wanted to focus most of time on business and application development. Below are list of PaaS providers who supports Node.js.

[Nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/),
[App42 PaaS](http://app42paas.shephertz.com/dev-center/node-platform-as-a-service/),
[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs),
[Appfog](https://docs.appfog.com/languages/node),
[Engine Yard](https://www.engineyard.com/techstack/node),
[OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/developers/node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not like a "tradational" web host like what you often find with php. Since you start up your own server in Node.js and you can't just use a server like apache (for the most part, as there are a few uncommon exceptions), tradational web hosting doesn't work because the security setup on those servers is designed around the fact that you have very little control over anything that happens on the server and can't break things on it, impossible using a web site made with Node.js. As the previous answer reccomends, go with a paas (Platform as a service) host. Notable PAAS hosters with decent free plan are [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you need "special" hosting that allows you to run node.js apps.
I'd suggest [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) - single dyno (" unit of computing power on Heroku, providing lightweight, isolated containers that run your app") for free.